# What settings should I use to resolve this GridBagLayout resizing issue?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, gridbaglayout

I have been searching and trying ways to resolve the problems I encountered with `GridBagLayout` resizing but to no avail. The problems are:

1. I drag the bottom of the `JDialog` window down to make it taller; the search panel (above panel in the below screenshot) kept getting taller, just adding white space that it didn't need for its contents (I don't want this wasted space which takes height away from the scrolling table below it).
2. If I move the right side of the window to make it a bit narrower, the scroll panel becomes too short even though my screen and the window could have displayed its full height; a vertical scroll bar appears (I don't like the panels to scroll vertically, just horizontally.)

My `JDialog` that holds below components in the upper right portion uses below layout manager and constraints:

```
JPanel      level 1         uses GridBagLayout Setting 1 (see below)
JScrollPane level 2         uses GridBagLayout Setting 1  
JPanel      level 3         uses GridBagLayout Setting 2
JPanel      level 4         uses GridBagLayout Setting 2
JPanel      level 5         uses GridBagLayout Setting 2
JPanel      level 5         uses GridBagLayout Setting 2
```

`GridBagLayout.GridBagConstraints` (c)

Setting 1:

```
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
c.weightx = 99.0;
c.weighty = 99.0;
```

Setting 2:

```
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
c.weightx = 1.0;
c.weighty = 1.0;
```

Originally, this is my `JDialog` if I don't use `JScrollPane`:

[image]

If I drag the window to make it bigger, the size of the `JPanel` (which was what I use before I used `JScrollPane` to make it scrollable horizontally) remains as it is. I want to achieve the same behavior, only that I want to make it horizontally scrollable.

What layout manager should I use to resolve this resizing problem? If I have to really use `GridBagLayout`, what constraints/settings should I use? I would highly appreciate any suggestion. Thank you!

**UPDATE 1 ------------------------------------------------------**

Kindly check sample code scenario below. Both scrollable panels (RED and BLUE) use `GridBagConstraints.BOTH`, `weightx` and `weighty` equal to `99.0`. I want the red panel to have a height that is enough to contain the text field. I also want that when the dialog is dragged down to make the window bigger, the red panel's height remains the same. Please note that in the actual screen, both panels' number of contents may change (add/minus buttons exist), hence, setting of minimum panel size (for resizing) won't help. Kindly advise how I should go about this case. Thanks!

```
package cfr.view.search;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class GBLSample extends JDialog {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    GBLSample frame = new GBLSample();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public GBLSample() {
        setBounds(100, 100, 350, 400);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        GridBagLayout gbl_contentPane = new GridBagLayout();
        contentPane.setLayout(gbl_contentPane);

        // RED PANEL ------------------------------------------------ 
        JScrollPane sp1 = new JScrollPane();
        GridBagConstraints gbc1 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc1.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc1.weightx = 99.0;
        gbc1.weighty = 99.0;
        contentPane.add(sp1, gbc1);

        JPanel redPanel = new JPanel();
        redPanel.setBackground(Color.RED);
        JTextField field = new JTextField(20);
        GridBagConstraints gbc2 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc2.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
        gbc2.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        contentPane.add(field, gbc2);

        redPanel.add(field);
        sp1.setViewportView(redPanel);

        // BLUE PANEL ------------------------------------------------ 
        JScrollPane sp2 = new JScrollPane();
        GridBagConstraints gbc3 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc3.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc3.gridx = 0;
        gbc3.gridy = 1;
        gbc3.weightx = 99.0;
        gbc3.weighty = 99.0;
        contentPane.add(sp2, gbc3);

        JPanel bluePanel = new JPanel();
        bluePanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        sp2.setViewportView(bluePanel);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2 ------------------------------------------------------**

Still have the same problem with the JPanel's sizing as #1 above.
Problem 1

[image]

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: To stop the vertical scrollbars from appearing you can use the policy `VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER` (see [Oracle Docs JScrollPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) ). And indeed, it's a bit hard to understand your problem at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I added a sample code that can hopefully describe the problem I want to fix. Any advice would be much appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there was a bug in the system's overridden JPanel.getMinimumSize() that was causing my search panel to get squished out of existence. I was able to find a fix for it already without changing any setting with the system's customized layout manager. Still, thanks a lot for all your answers and help.

Answer (score 2):

try this code:

```
package test;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class GridBagLayoutSample extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                GridBagLayoutSample frame = new GridBagLayoutSample();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public GridBagLayoutSample() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    GridBagLayout gbl_contentPane = new GridBagLayout();
    gbl_contentPane.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0};
    gbl_contentPane.rowHeights = new int[]{50, 0, 0};
    //the 1.0 value in columnWeights let redPanel and scrollPane (that contain bleuPanel) grow horizontally
    //the 1.0 value is in the first index so it affect the first column
    //you still need to use a valid value for gbc_redPanel.fill and gbc_scrollPane.fill;
    gbl_contentPane.columnWeights = new double[]{1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
    //the 0.0 value of rowWeights => components in first row will not grow
    //the 0.0 value of rowWeights => components in second row will grow
    gbl_contentPane.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, 1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
    contentPane.setLayout(gbl_contentPane);

    JPanel redPanel = new JPanel();
    redPanel.setBackground(Color.RED);
    GridBagConstraints gbc_redPanel = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_redPanel.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
    gbc_redPanel.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc_redPanel.gridx = 0;
    gbc_redPanel.gridy = 0;
    contentPane.add(redPanel, gbc_redPanel);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    GridBagConstraints gbc_scrollPane = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_scrollPane.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc_scrollPane.gridx = 0;
    gbc_scrollPane.gridy = 1;
    contentPane.add(scrollPane, gbc_scrollPane);

    JPanel bleuPanel = new JPanel();
    bleuPanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    //scrollpane work with the preferred size of the component in the viewportView
    //try to change this values
    bleuPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
    scrollPane.setViewportView(bleuPanel);
}
```

}

add this to your code

```
gbl_contentPane.rowHeights = new int[]{40, 0, 0};
gbl_contentPane.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0,0.0, 1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
gbc1.gridx = 0;
gbc1.gridy = 0;
```

and remove this

```
gbc1.weightx = 99.0;
gbc1.weighty = 99.0;
```

Comment: Thanks sami for your suggestion, but I think what I want is a bit different to your given scenario. Can you please check my above sample and additional comment?

Comment: this wasn't able to solve my problem. The search panel's heights are variable (depends on a type), hence; I cannot set rowHeights explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

> I have been searching and trying ways to resolve the problems I encountered with `GridBagLayout` resizing but to no avail.

Welcome to `GridBagLayout`.

First thing to note is that in

```
        JPanel redPanel = new JPanel();
        redPanel.setBackground(Color.RED);
        JTextField field = new JTextField(20);
//      GridBagConstraints gbc2 = new GridBagConstraints();
//      gbc2.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
//      gbc2.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
//      contentPane.add(field, gbc2);

        redPanel.add(field);
        sp1.setViewportView(redPanel);
```

You are adding the text field to the content pane and then adding it again to the panel, which overrides your previous assignment (a component can only belong to one container). I commented out the lines which do nothing. The choice for how to lay out the text field in the red panel is completely different than the choice of how to lay out the red panel in the content pane.

> I want the red panel to have a height that is enough to contain the text field.

That is taken care of by the layout manager. However, if you resize the window manually so that the panel will not have enough space, then scrollbars will appear provided that the panel is in a `JScrollPane`. You can try to `@Override` the `getMinimumSize` of the panel to its `getPreferredSize`, but not all layout managers respect it, I believe.

Regardless, I don't see why you need the scroll pane for the red panel at all.

> I also want that when the dialog is dragged down to make the window bigger, the red panel's height remains the same.

Then you should set its `weighty` to `0`.

**Note:** don't use underscores (`_`) in non-final variable names in accordance with the Java naming conventions (`gbl_contentPane` should be `gblContentPane`).

**Edit**

Here is an example of of dynamically changing the allocated size for the `redPanel`. I use `BorderLayout` for the content pane (also suggested by Dan O) for simplicity.

```
public class GBLSample extends JDialog {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JScrollPane redSP = new JScrollPane(new RedPanel());

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            GBLSample frame = new GBLSample();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    private class RedPanel extends JPanel {

        RedPanel() {

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            setBackground(Color.RED);

            GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
            c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
            add(new JTextField(10), c);
            c.weightx = 1;
            c.gridx = 1;
            add(new JComboBox<>(), c);
            c.weightx = 0;
            c.gridx = 0;
            add(new JComboBox<>(), c);
            c.gridx = 1;
            add(new JComboBox<>(), c);
            c.weighty = 1;
            c.gridx = 0;
            c.gridy = 2;
            add(new JButton("SSSS"), c);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {

            Dimension dim = super.getPreferredSize();
            JScrollBar sb = redSP.getHorizontalScrollBar();
            if (!sb.isShowing())
                return dim;
            return new Dimension(dim.width, dim.height + sb.getHeight());
        }
    }

    public GBLSample() {

        setBounds(100, 100, 350, 400);
        contentPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        // RED PANEL ------------------------------------------------
        redSP.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        contentPane.add(redSP, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        // BLUE PANEL ------------------------------------------------
        JPanel bluePanel = new JPanel();
        bluePanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        contentPane.add(new JScrollPane(bluePanel));
    }
}
```

The idea is to add all extra space at the bottom of the panel by giving all the weight to a component on the bottom (and similarly can be done for the x axis with a right-most component). When the scrollbar is shown, the panel recalculates its height and adds the scrollbar's height to to itself (to the bottom most component), then the scrollbar does not hide anything.

Comment: Thanks @user1803551. Really appreciate your help. If I change my weighty to 0, then drag the window to the left to make it a bit narrower, my text field in the red panel gets squished out of existence.

Comment: Regardless, I don't see why you need the scroll pane for the red panel at all.
<-- My actual search panel contains many contents, the scroll pane targets to help those with narrow screens. Other than using a scroll pane, do you have other suggestion that would make the red panel scrollable?

Comment: @IamRiz How small is the screen? Mobile device? These have their own GUI design paradigms.

Comment: @IamRiz Besides scroll bars, you can use a `JTabbedPane` or a `JSplitPane` as a way to conserve space. To know if it makes sense one would need to know what this component is responsible for.

Comment: no it's not a mobile device, maybe just smaller than a 12-inch screen. The component is a search panel which is responsible in providing one or many search filters/options for users. Hence, the panel should resize when user clicks +/- search items, but not when the screen is dragged to make the window bigger.

Comment: @IamRiz I don't know what are the "*+/- search items*" and in general a panel shouldn't be resized unless the user resizes the containing window. As for "*my text field in the red panel gets squished out of existence*"; the scrollbars are part of the scroll pane, so when they appear they are alloted space from the viewport, which means that they can appear over components in the viewport. When you have just 1 text field it can look bad since most of the viewport is taken over by the scrollbar, but if you add more components then it should be fine. You can update your question with more code.

Comment: I still haven't solved the problem. The JScrollPane set its size in respect to its container's JPanel size. http://i.stack.imgur.com/rLffu.jpg

Comment: @IamRiz As I understand it, you can solve problem 1 by setting `weighty = 0`, but then when the horizontal scrollbar appears it covers the components. You will need to allocate space from the blue panel to have enough height for the additional scrollbar. That is, the `redpanel`'s scroll pane will resize dynamically. Am I understanding this correctly? What layout manager do you want to use for the `redPanel`?

Comment: I already tried weighty = 0, but you're correct that when the horizontal scrollbar appears it covers the components. Both redPanel and bluePanel uses GridBagLayout and should resize dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a `GridBagLayout` might not be suited for your current UI, and a [`BorderLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html) would work better?  Put the red panel in `BorderLayout.NORTH` and put the blue panel in `BorderLayout.CENTER`.  Components in the CENTER region will grow and shrink as you resize your dialog, and your red panel's preferredSize will be respected as you +/- items.

Comment: While the usage of `BorderLayout` is easier for the current state of the GUI, I wouldn't go as far as advising "*do not use a `GridBagLayout`*". It is perfectly acceptable both practically and educationally considering we can't know how the GUI will evolve.

Comment: oh absolutely - GBL can definitely be used here.  But some of the language in the question ("What layout manager should I use to resolve this resizing problem? If I have to really use GridBagLayout, what constraints/settings should I use?") seemed to leave things open for alternatives.

Comment: True. Then maybe consider rephrasing to something like  "I would recommend to not use..." or "it is more fitting to use ... than to use ... " with a mention of "at the GUI's current state"?

Comment: @Dan O, I tried your suggestion, but the scroll panel doesn't respect its client component's resizing. The search panel isn't vertically scrollable, hence; when the client becomes bigger than JScrollPane's viewport size, the bottom components isn't visible.

Comment: did you try validating (or invalidating) your `Container`?